# Turn Off Tree Reflections For Glass And Gloss BSDF?

Tags: reflection

I'm pretty experienced with Blender, but one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to turn off those weird tree reflections in the Glass/Gloss BSDF.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Just go to the top right of the viewport where viewport shading is and click the arrow. Then, turn down the strength.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just propose another solution:

**1) Switch to your World lighting**
This will use your environment texture for lighting.
If there's no HDRi set, *no image texture* will be reflected.
You're done.

*No texture is reflected, only homogenous light*
[image]

**2) Enable your scene lights**
This will give you a better preview of your render.
You can combine it with your World lighting.

*No image texture is reflected, plus your scene lights are enabled.*
[image]

---

**Why not just turn lighting strength to zero.**

It makes all materials look the same (black).
While this works for getting rid of texture reflections, it is not often desired.
Simply switching to you World settings is usually more convenient.

*Scene looks with lighting strength set to zero.*
[image]